# React Js client side routing similar to angular routing or stateRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm from angular background and looking into ReactJs now. I successfully started to understand the components logic of thinking, and im trying to visualise the same in angular, now I'm wondering how to implement routing for an Single page app which barely consumes REST api's. i looked [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) and these examples talks about server side rendering(or i understood that way, i dont what npm install, im thinking like we add a js to html and configure routes as we do in angular ?), im not writing isomorphic js for now. can anyone help me to learn how to implement client side routing in ReactJs, or if I'm completely misunderstood please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactJS supports both serverside and clientside routing(Single page Application). Use react-router hashHistory or browserHistory for client Side routing

```js
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink,hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

render((
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Root}>    
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />    
    <Route path="blog" component={BlogPage} /> 
    <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} /> 
    <Route path="logout" component={LogoutPage} onEnter={onLogoutEnter}/> 
  </Route>
   </Router>
), document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: 'react-router' where you get this package, is this installed from npm ?

Comment: Yes.  npm install --save react-router

Comment: I dont want to use npm install, can i use the lib just by adding in html and use it in js ?

Comment: If you are creating Single page Application.  Use webpack or browserify  to   generate as single bundle file.

Comment: Im following these tutorial from official guide, here they dont use npm https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html also if i added the above link you pointed and tried to use your code above it throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Comment: can you guide me with some complete examples or links. Im looking for example without npms thanks for your help